# Stuck in login loop after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade

I just upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, and now I can’t get past my login screen. TTY terminals are available.

Things I have tried:

- Reinstalling and reconfiguring lightdm
- Changing permissions and ownership of .ICEauthority and .Xauthority files
- Nothing interesting in lightdm logs or in .xsession-errors
- Deleting all Gnome extensions
- Deleting .local directory
- Reinstall GDM, gnome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 and login into the shell.
when the terminal is opened install nvideia driver using the cmd **sudo apt install nvidia-384** the above steps worked for me when i have the same issue

or you can check the following link if above doesnt work for you
[login screen on loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)